# Problem when stores dict into pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Recently in my project, I need to store a dictionary into a Pandas DataFrame with the code

```
self.device_info.loc[i,'interference']=[temp_dict]
```

The device_info is a Pandas DataFrame. The temp_dict is a dictionary and I want it to be stored as an element in the DataFrame for future use. The square bracket is added to ensure there's no error when assigning.

I just found it today that with Pandas version 0.22.0, this code will pack the dictionary as a list and store it into the DataFrame. However, in the version of 0.24.2, this code directly stores the dictionary into Pandas DataFrame.

For example, say when i=0, after executing the code
with Pandas.**version** == '0.22.0'

```
type(self.device_info.loc[0,'interference'])
```

returns list, while Pandas.**version** == '0.24.2', this code returns a dict. From my perspective, I need a consistent performance that there is always a dictionary stored.

I am currently working on two PCs, one's home and one's at my office, and I cannot update the older version of pandas on my office PC. So I would be much appreciated if anyone can help me figure out why this happens.

Comment: Just use a venv on your home pc to have pandas 0.22 on it!

Comment: What @BlueSheepToken said above or store your dictionary as a 'json'

Answer (score -1):

Pandas has a [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) method with many option which takes a `dict` as input and returns a `DataFrame`.
You can chose to infer type or force it (to `str`, for example).

Then, manipulating and appending dataframes is way easier as you won't ever again have `dict` object problem in that line or column.

Comment: This is not what the op is asking, I would not be surprise if your answer get downvoted :/